# Compile error MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm getting a compile error: "Argument not optional" 
Basically in this code, I'm trying to do a around the table style auto-assigning. When the code is called, it starts at `AssignNullProjects()` and when I get the error, `GetNextAssignee` is highlight in the part `" & GetNextAssignee & "`

I'm not really sure how to fix it, here's my full code below:

```
Public Function AssignNullProjects() As Long

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID, [program], [language] FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        While Not rs.EOF
            strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee & ", assignedby = " & [Forms]![CFRRR]![assignedby] & ", Dateassigned = #" & Now & "#, actiondate = #" & Now & "#, Workername = " & _
                              [Forms]![CFRRR]![assignedto] & ", WorkerID = " & [Forms]![CFRRR]![assignedto] & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID

            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function

Public Function GetNextAssignee(program As String, Language As String) As Long
'   Returns UserID as a Long Integer with the lowest [TS] value,
'   and updates same [TS] by incremented with 1.

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM attendance WHERE [Programs] LIKE '*" & program & "*' AND [Language] = '" & Language & "' AND [Status] = '" & Available & "' ORDER BY TS ASC"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        'Found next assignee, update date/time stamp
'        strSQL = "UPDATE tblUser SET TS = " & DMax("[TS]", tblUser) + 1 & " WHERE [WorkerID]= " & rs!workerid
        strSQL = "UPDATE attendance SET TS = " & DMax("[TS]", "attendance") + 1 & " WHERE [WorkerID]= " & rs!workerid
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        GetNextAssignee = rs!workerid
    Else
        'Field TS has NO VALUE FOR ALL RECORDS!
        'Code calling this function should check for a return of 0 indicating an error.
        GetNextAssignee = 0
    End If

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: `GetNextAssignee` clearly requires two parameters (`program` and `Language`), as shown in the declaration; your calling code provides neither of them with `& GetAssignee &`). What else would you expect to happen? "In order to be delivered by the postal service, your letter requires two things: a delivery address, and a stamp with sufficient postage. You've provided neither of them. We cannot complete your request for delivery of this letter."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call this function, you must supply 2 arguments (string values):

```vb
Public Function GetNextAssignee(program As String, Language As String) As Long
```

But when building your `UPDATE` statement, you call that function without supplying the required arguments:

```vb
strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee & ", assignedby = "
```

So Access is complaining that those (string) arguments are not optional --- you must supply them.  Your code should compile when you give the function 2 strings like this ...

```vb
strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee("foo", "bar") & ", assignedby = "
```

Although the code would compile with those strings, the function would probably not return the result you need. So substitute realistic values in place of *foo* and *bar*.

Comment: Do I type it just as I have it in the function? `" & GetNextAssignee(program As String, Language As String) As Long & "` but I'm getting an error saying list separator or ) and `As` is highlighted.

Comment: Great that did the trick, now I'm getting an error on the bottom half, saying too few parameters: expected 2. `strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM attendance WHERE [Programs] LIKE '*" & program & "*' AND [Language] = '" & Language & "' AND [Status] = " & ("Available") & " ORDER BY TS ASC"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)` I can ask another question though.

Comment: Yes, that is a different problem, so a new question for it is the way to go.  When you write that question, please paste in the output from `Debug.Print strSQL` when you encounter the new error.  It's better to show us the actual failing statement than only the code which creates the statement.

Comment: Question asked with the Debug.Print entered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142827/too-few-parameters-error-ms-access-sql