# Too few parameters error MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm getting a run-time error: too few parameters: expected 2.

This code is supposed to get the next employee in line for assignments. The employees `[programs]` and `[Language]` have to match the `[program]` and `[language]` in the table CFRRR.

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM attendance WHERE [Programs] LIKE '*" & program & "*' AND [Language] = '" & Language & "' AND [Status] = " & ("Available") & " ORDER BY TS ASC"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```

Here's what `Debug.Print strSQL` shows me:

`SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM attendance WHERE [Programs] LIKE '*program*' AND [Language] LIKE '*Language*' AND [Status] = Available ORDER BY TS ASC`

Comment: Have you tried putting single quotes around the status?: 'Available'

Comment: I just did that and got the same error except this time it said expected 1 and here's the debug.print: `SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM attendance WHERE [Programs] LIKE '*program*' AND [Language] LIKE '*Language*' AND [Status] = 'Available' ORDER BY TS ASC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want `[Status]` to match the word *Available*, add quotes as Mark [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142827/too-few-parameters-error-ms-access-sql/30142995#comment48394301_30142827) ...

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM attendance
WHERE [Programs] LIKE '*program*' AND [Language] LIKE '*Language*' AND [Status] = 'Available'
ORDER BY TS ASC
```

However that still leaves one "parameter" unaccounted for.  Create a new query in the Access query designer.  Switch to SQL View and paste in your statement text.

When you try to run that query, Access will pop up an input dialog asking you to supply a value for the parameter.  That dialog also includes the word which Access assumes to be the parameter.

Compare that word with your SQL statement.  It is generally a misspelled object (field or table) name, function, or SQL keyword.  In this case, I can't spot function or keyword errors, so will guess the problem is a field or table name.

Comment: That worked. I found my error and it wasn't even what I thought it was but now I have another error. It is saying it cannot find my my referenced form CFRRR and there is definitely a form there.  Should I ask another question?

Comment: Hmm.  *CFRRR* isn't mentioned in the query, so that surprised me.  Do you maybe need a query which joins *attendance* and *CFRRR*?  If so, yes, I think that is a different question.

Comment: You're right. It was on my other question.  I'll just ask another question.

Comment: OK.  On a positive note, your questions are getting better each time.  :-)

Comment: Hahahahha right! I feel like I'm starting to understand more and more. Here's my other question.  I'm on my cell so I don't know if it came out all weird.  It looks weird to me haha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143343/form-not-found-error-ms-access-sql

Comment: *cough cough* *wink wink* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147937/parameters-error-with-two-tables-ms-access-sql ;)