# Parameters Error with two tables MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to adjust this coding to select only userID's from table Attendance where [Programs] and [Language] match those form table CFRRR but I'm getting an error saying that I have too few parameters. I'm sure but it may be because I'm not referring to the other table here: `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)`

Here's the full code:

```
Public Function GetNextAssignee(program As String, language As String, username As String) As Long
'   Returns UserID as a Long Integer with the lowest [TS] value,
'   and updates same [TS] by incremented with 1.

    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 userID FROM attendance WHERE [Programs] LIKE CFRRR.program  AND [Language] LIKE CFRRR.language AND [Status] = 'Available' ORDER BY TS ASC"
    Debug.Print strSQL
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        strSQL = "UPDATE attendance SET TS = " & DMax("[TS]", "attendance") + 1 & " WHERE [userID]= " & rs!userID
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        GetNextAssignee = rs!userID
        GetNextWorker = rs!username
    Else
        'Field TS has NO VALUE FOR ALL RECORDS!
        'Code calling this function should check for a return of 0 indicating an error.
        GetNextAssignee = 0
    End If

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: The `SELECT` query is the cause of the error.  The `UPDATE` query, and really all of the VBA code, are just distractions at this point.  So take the `SELECT` and work on it in the query designer.  (`LIKE CFRRR.program` is a problem because `CFRRR` is not included in the `FROM` clause.)  You would be wise to forget about the VBA until you have a `SELECT` which runs without error and returns the results you need.

Comment: Additionally, the VBA recordset references a username that is not included in select query. You may not even need the recordset as the select query can be saved as a stored query and the update uses a DLookup: `UPDATE attendance SET TS = " & DMax("[TS]", "attendance") + 1 & " WHERE [userID]= " & DLookUp("userID", "newqueryname")`. In fact, the update sql can be a saved action query called on by `DoCmd.OpenQuery`!

Comment: Thank you @ HansUp! You're always so helpful and you teach at the same which double helps! I was able to get through it. Also @Parfait, you're right I didn't have username correctly there. I actually removed it and went a different route. Thank you!