# form not found error. MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm getting an error saying that Access cannot find the referenced form CFRRR but there is definitely a form there. Not sure if I'm just not writing the code correctly.

```
Public Function AssignNullProjects() As Long 
    Dim db As dao.Database 
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset 
    Dim strSQL As String 
    Set db = CurrentDb 
    strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID, [program], [language] FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null" 
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset) 
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then 
        While Not rs.EOF 
            strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee & ", assignedby = " & [Forms]![CFRRR]![assignedby] & ", Dateassigned = #" & Now & "#, actiondate = #" & Now & "#, Workername = " & _ [Forms]![CFRRR]![assignedto] & ", WorkerID = " & [Forms]![CFRRR]![assignedto] & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError 
            rs.MoveNext 
        Wend 
    End If 
    rs.Close 
    db.Close 
    Set rs = Nothing 
    Set db = Nothing
End Function 

Public Function GetNextAssignee(program As String, Language As String) As Long 
    ' Returns UserID as a Long Integer with the lowest [TS] value, 
    ' and updates same [TS] by incremented with 1. 
    Dim db As dao.Database 
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset 
    Dim strSQL As String 
    Set db = CurrentDb 
    strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 WorkerID FROM attendance WHERE [Programs] LIKE '*" & program & "*' AND [Language] = '" & Language & "' AND [Status] = '" & Available & "' ORDER BY TS ASC" 
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset) 
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then 
        'Found next assignee, update date/time stamp 
        'strSQL = "UPDATE tblUser SET TS = " & DMax("[TS]", tblUser) + 1 & " WHERE [WorkerID]= " & rs!workerid 
        strSQL = "UPDATE attendance SET TS = " & DMax("[TS]", "attendance") + 1 & " WHERE [WorkerID]= " & rs!workerid 
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError 
        GetNextAssignee = rs!workerid 
    Else 
        'Field TS has NO VALUE FOR ALL RECORDS! 
        'Code calling this function should check for a return of 0 indicating an error. 
        GetNextAssignee = 0 
    End If 
    rs.Close
    db.Close 
    Set rs = Nothing 
    Set db = Nothing 
End Function
```

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'm on my cell in the car so I was just trying to copy and paste from my other question.  It's the same code but now I'm getting the referenced form not found error. Here's how it properly looks like on my other question. I'll fix my question when I get some internet on my laptop.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135585/compile-error-ms-access-sql/30136106#30136106

Comment: Thank you @pekka for fixing my code!  I think the error may be referring to this part of my code `[Forms]![CFRRR]![assignedby]`

Comment: Run this in the Immediate window to show you the names (as Access knows them) of all forms which are currently open: `for each frm in forms : ? frm.name : next`

Comment: Do I literally type that in the immediate window?

Comment: Just copy the highlighted statement from my comment, paste it as a single line in the Immediate window, and press Enter.  If it doesn't show you anything, make sure Access thinks you have at least one form open: `? forms.count`

Comment: Okay so I got it the immediate window to populate and my form isn't populating which after looking at my code and my form structure that makes sense. I have a login system and the a form with navigationsubforms. So I adjusted my code but it's still not populating my form in the immediate window. `assignedto = " & Forms! [Supervisor]! [Navigationsubform]!.Form! [CFRRR]![Assignedto] & "`